# Organizer's Developer Profile disappeared in xcode4.3?

Tags: xcode4.3

In Xcode4.2,we can see Developer Profile at Organizer
[image]

But in Xcode4.3, it's disappeared.
[image]
Then,how to import my Developer provisioning profile into Xcode4.3 or where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the devices organizer:

1. Select your team in the Teams section.
2. Click Import.
3. Select the file containing your code signing assets.
4. Enter the password for the file, and click Open.

Troubleshooting: **If you don’t see the Team section in the devices organizer**:

- Drag the password-protected file that contains your code signing assets to the Xcode icon in the Dock.

From this Apple tech note:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Devices/Devices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH12-SW16

Answer (score 1):

Click refresh and enter your credentials?

Comment: Thank you for reply, but it didn't help:(